# Clearing trig pin in C, Arduino coding

Tags: arduino, embedded

I am new to Arduino coding. I'm trying on code related to ultrasonic sensor.

```
digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
//this to clear pin
```

I am not able to get what this code is for (what is meant by clearing pin). Do I need to clear pin every time before I send a sound wave to detect motion?

Comment: that depends on what `trigPin` is  and to what and how is interconnected. What MCU is this for?  (and please do not respond Arduino as that is just framework) Without circuitry and background knowledge has program no meaning. Is this output or input ... If input it is polling or interrupt. Is the receiver/tranceiver connected directly or through some driver and which one ? You want continuous signal (interference) or pulses (time of travel)

Comment: Those two lines just set a pin to 0V (often referred to as clearing a pin as opposed to setting it which would be to write it to HIGH) and then delays for 2 microseconds.  Why that has some given effect depends on what is connected to that pin. You haven't given any context to talk about that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you've been getting the code from [there](http://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04/).

```
// Clears the trigPin
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);

// Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
```

"Clearing" here is in fact making sure you're sending no sound wave at all before starting to send some so that a clear and abrupt wave front is emitted.

```
              __________
              |        |
signal  ______|        |______________

          <--> <------->
           2us    10us
```

We want to make sure we are low before being high. As a result the received waves would have a higher chance of being correctly identified.

```
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
```

What `pulseIn()` does is that it waits for a sound wave to enter the sensor and create a signal that is higher than a threshold in volts.

A [great explanation](https://www.davidpilling.com/wiki/index.php/HCSR04) of how it works.